# Difference between get _the_ excerpt and get_the_content

Tags: wordpress

What is the difference between functions get the excerpt and get the content. Both returns the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main difference between both is :

> *get_the_excerpt* returns summary of the posts or we can say that short 
>   content of the post or the content written in Post Excerpt metabox.
>   `excerpt` length can be altered by `excerpt_length` filter

Example:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

> While *get_the_content* returns full content of the posts (i.e., all the content that is added in posts.)

**USAGE**

- *get_the_excerpt* : used in listing all the posts (i.e., archive page) with the title and short content.
- *get_the_content* : used when we are display single post.

---

Reference:

- [the_content vs the_excerpt](http://weblines.com.au/learning-wordpress/the_content-v-the_excerpt)
- [get_the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)